# Not able to set default value from a variable in OutlinedTextField

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am working on android app with Compose, I have a form that user fills and it gets added to a list, if the user taps on item again in the list I need to show the form again with data filled in.

Following is my code:

```
var name by remember { mutableStateOf(inventoryItem.name ?: "") }
OutlinedTextField(
    value = name,
    onValueChange = { name = it },
    label = { Text("Item") },
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
 )
```

But instead of setting the value from variable it shows empty value. If I hardcode the name in mutbaleStateOf it works. mutableStateOf is not accepting default value from a variable.

I expect to fill the textfield with item information, please suggest what can I do to fill the textfield with data from a variable as each item int the list will have different data.

Comment: `inventoryItem.name` is from viewmodel or some where else?

Comment: Hi @ABINASHKUMAR yes "inventoryItem.name" is from viewmodel

Comment: Need more code on how this variable is being used in this Composable fuction